# 401 Invalid credentials when using OAuth2.0 after some idle time

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

Am reading [this page](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/) by Boris Smus and tried to implement and everything is working good. The only problem is, the requests are failing after some time. Am using googleapis. As soon as I install my test extension and try to make some googleapi requests, they are passing. But aftersome time when I try the same they are failing.
In the background.js NET tab i see the following response.

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }
```

If I just reload my extension everything is working fine again. Am thinking it is something to do with accesstoken but am not sure how/where to fix it.

Also what I observed from console tab of background.js page, google.isAccessTokenExpired() results in 'false' when everything is working. It returns TRUE when everything is failing. Where/How do I fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Added the following code.

```
if(google.isAccessTokenExpired()) { 
    google.authorize(function() { myFunc(info); } );
}
```

Not sure why it dint't worked a while back. Now its working.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked fine for the userinfo API. But not for contacts API. The problem was solved by changing the Url for contacts from http to https

So the Url I used: https://www.googleapis.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full